# What does 「再々起」mean?

Tags: meaning, words

> ６月には日本でのデビュー３０周年を記念したコンサートを開き「**再々起**」を目指す

Source: https://www.sankei.com/premium/news/190429/prm1904290009-n1.html (last line of first paragraph)

I think it means most frequently sung songs but I am not sure. I understand 再々 as 'often' and 起 as 'occur/beginning' but I am confused about what the combination means.

Comment: 再々 used in place of 再 can mean "re-re-". For example, 再々発 is "re-recurrence (of a cancer)", 再々建 is "re-rebuild", 再々受験 is "third trial (of an exam)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are reading way too much into it.

「再起{さいき}」 means "a return to popularity" and

「再々起{さいさいき}」 means "a **second** return to popularity".  In other words, it means "a re-comeback".

The popularity of キム・ヨンジャ, the singer who was once very successful in Japan, declined greatly for the "problems" in her personal life.  When she returned to her home country of South Korea, however, she became quite popular again there, which was her 「再起」.  Now, she is aiming for her 「再々起」 back in Japan by giving a concert this coming June.

The reason that the word 「再々起」 is quoted in the article would be that it is not a word usually found in dictionaries.

Comment: I did not know the word 再起 (comeback) which is the reason I did not understand 再々起. You answer clarifies a lot. Thank you :). In the hindsight it does seem like I thought too much. Haha.